# PHP - Use mysql_fetch_assoc() multiple times in the loop.

Tags: php

I'm working on a really simple email notification system for newly added comments. It works like this:

1. loop through project users
2. for each user, loop through all comments written in the last hour
3. if there are any comments that are not written by the user, push them to an array
4. if comment array is not empty, send an email to the user

Here's some of the code:

```
<?php
$users_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

$comments_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments c, users u WHERE c.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) and c.user_id = u.id");

while ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($users_query)) {
   $commentsArr = array();  

   while ($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments_query)) {
      if ($comment['email'] != $user['email']) {
         array_push($commentsArr, $comment['comment']);
      }
   }

   // send $commentsArr by email to $user['email']
}
?>
```

The problem is that the same `mysql_fetch_assoc` cannot be used multiple times on a single page. I tried reseting the pointer using `mysql_data_seek($comments_query, 0);` but that just threw the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_data_seek() [function.mysql-data-seek]: Offset 0 is invalid for MySQL result index 4 (or the query data is unbuffered)
```

Are there any other ways of handling this? All other people with similar questions were advised to join their tables instead of splitting them up. I don't think I can do that since I have to go through all users first, so if I join them, I'll have more rows than users.

Anyway, is there a way to loop through the comments while inside a loop?

Comment: you shouldn't use mysql_ as it is depreciated, use mysqli_ instead or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched from `mysql` to `mysqli` and now `mysqli_data_seek($comments_query, 0);` works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$users_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$users = mysql_fetch_array($users_query);

$comments_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments c, users u WHERE c.date >    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) and c.user_id = u.id");

$comments = mysql_fetch_array($comments_query)

foreach($user as $users) {
  $commentsArr = array();  

  foreach($comment as $comments) {
    if ($comment['email'] != $user['email']) {
     array_push($commentsArr, $comment['comment']);
    }
  }

  // send $commentsArr by email to $user['email']
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $commentsArr array in outside of the while loop:

```
 <?php
    $users_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

    $comments_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments c, users u WHERE c.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) and c.user_id = u.id");
    $commentsArr = array();  
    while ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($users_query)) {


       while ($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments_query)) {
          if ($comment['email'] != $user['email']) {
             array_push($commentsArr, $comment['comment']);
          }
       }

       // send $commentsArr by email to $user['email']
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: That won't make a difference, as the problem is with `mysql_fetch_assoc` being called multiple times.

Comment: if you calling inside the while loop means it shows an empty array.